# How to get data from Google Sheets to another Google Sheets with conditional

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to get data from :

[Google Sheet #A1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4k8H08Bc5rI5WFXNHcpmWL-Sjzis9gV3-0N2imAAww/edit#gid=0)

to
[Google Sheet #A2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J0DP8_meNURDY_VG7Bn1aQPvXVCnpwfnM8iGpknYFJc/edit#gid=1241187482)

(Only **Gadget** product from Sheet A1 and empty strings for prices)

Please advise me the formula for obtaining information.

Thank you
PRADIT SK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One formula in one cell:

```
={
  QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE(
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4k8H08Bc5rI5WFXNHcpmWL-Sjzis9gV3-0N2imAAww",
      "'Sheet-1'!A:E"
    ),
    "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
     WHERE     Col1 IS NOT NULL
           AND Col3 = 'Gadget'",
    1
  ),
  {
    "PRICE";
    TRANSPOSE(
      SPLIT(
        REPT(
          ",",
          QUERY(
            IMPORTRANGE(
              "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4k8H08Bc5rI5WFXNHcpmWL-Sjzis9gV3-0N2imAAww",
              "'Sheet-1'!A:E"
            ),
            "SELECT COUNT(Col1)
             WHERE     Col1 IS NOT NULL
                   AND Col3 = 'Gadget'
             GROUP BY Col3
             LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''",
            1
          ) - 1
        ),
        ",",
        1,
        0
      )
    )
  },
  QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE(
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4k8H08Bc5rI5WFXNHcpmWL-Sjzis9gV3-0N2imAAww",
      "'Sheet-1'!A:E"
    ),
    "SELECT Col5
     WHERE     Col1 IS NOT NULL
           AND Col3 = 'Gadget'",
    1
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment:  Thank you very much.